# nginx - php of subdirectory is returning 404

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

I'm getting 404 errors on php pages from a sub-location of my host.
My configuration is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/nisite;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  www2.company.com wp-newsite-stg-02.company.com;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index            index.php;
    fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    include                  fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

  # =================================

    location /office {
        root /var/www/html/oldsite;
    }

}
```

When I go to `http://www2.company.com/office` I can see the page, all of the static assets are served as well, but when I try to access `http://www2.company.com/office/php/form-process.php` I get 404 error.

why doesn't the `location ~ \.php$` handles this request right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` block inherits the value for `$document_root` from the `root` statement in the surrounding block. You are running PHP scripts from two separate roots, so you need two separate `location` blocks to handle them.

The solution is to use a nested `location` block.

For example:

```
location ^~ /office {
    root /var/www/html/oldsite;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Use the `^~` modifier to ensure that the correct `location` processes the `.php` files. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details. Use the `try_files` statement to avoid [passing uncontrolled requests to php](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php)